# JavaScript ES6 side nav issue when function call

Tags: javascript, html, function, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I'm building a side nav with JavaScript ES6 and I started with the Supercharged-Show code example. I made a toggle button to replace the show and the hide ones. I try to use my `toggleSideNav` function to call the `showSideNav` but nothing happen. I'm probably missing something with the `this`.

My HTML page looks like this :

```
<body>
  <header class="header">
    <!--<button class="js-menu-show header__menu-toggle material-icons">menu</button>-->
    <hc-hamburger role="button" class="js-menu">
      <div class="hamburger-menu">
        <div class="bar"></div>
      </div>
    </hc-hamburger>
  </header>

  <aside class="js-side-nav side-nav">
    <nav class="js-side-nav-container side-nav__container">
      <!--<button class="js-menu-hide side-nav__hide material-icons">close</button>-->
      <header class="side-nav__header">
        Side Nav
      </header>
      <ul class="side-nav__content">
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
        <li>Four</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </aside>
  <script src='./detabinator.js'></script>
  <script src='./side-nav.js'></script>
  <script src='./hamburger.js'></script>
</body>
```

And my JS file like this :

```
'use strict';

class SideNav {
  constructor () {
    this.toggleMenuEl = document.querySelector('.js-menu');
    this.showButtonEl = document.querySelector('.js-menu-show');
    this.hideButtonEl = document.querySelector('.js-menu-hide');
    this.sideNavEl = document.querySelector('.js-side-nav');
    this.sideNavContainerEl = document.querySelector('.js-side-nav-container');
    // Control whether the container's children can be focused
    // Set initial state to inert since the drawer is offscreen
    this.detabinator = new Detabinator(this.sideNavContainerEl);
    this.detabinator.inert = true;

    this.toggleSideNav = this.toggleSideNav.bind(this);
    this.showSideNav = this.showSideNav.bind(this);
    this.hideSideNav = this.hideSideNav.bind(this);
    this.blockClicks = this.blockClicks.bind(this);
    this.onTouchStart = this.onTouchStart.bind(this);
    this.onTouchMove = this.onTouchMove.bind(this);
    this.onTouchEnd = this.onTouchEnd.bind(this);
    this.onTransitionEnd = this.onTransitionEnd.bind(this);
    this.update = this.update.bind(this);

    this.startX = 0;
    this.currentX = 0;
    this.touchingSideNav = false;

    this.supportsPassive = undefined;
    this.addEventListeners();
  }

  // apply passive event listening if it's supported
  applyPassive () {
    if (this.supportsPassive !== undefined) {
      return this.supportsPassive ? {passive: true} : false;
    }
    // feature detect
    let isSupported = false;
    try {
      document.addEventListener('test', null, {get passive () {
        isSupported = true;
      }});
    } catch (e) { }
    this.supportsPassive = isSupported;
    return this.applyPassive();
  }

  addEventListeners () {
    this.toggleMenuEl.addEventListener('click', this.toggleSideNav);
    // this.showButtonEl.addEventListener('click', this.showSideNav);
    // this.hideButtonEl.addEventListener('click', this.hideSideNav);
    this.sideNavEl.addEventListener('click', this.hideSideNav);
    this.sideNavContainerEl.addEventListener('click', this.blockClicks);

    this.sideNavEl.addEventListener('touchstart', this.onTouchStart, this.applyPassive());
    this.sideNavEl.addEventListener('touchmove', this.onTouchMove, this.applyPassive());
    this.sideNavEl.addEventListener('touchend', this.onTouchEnd);
  }

  onTouchStart (evt) {
    if (!this.sideNavEl.classList.contains('side-nav--visible'))
      return;

    this.startX = evt.touches[0].pageX;
    this.currentX = this.startX;

    this.touchingSideNav = true;
    requestAnimationFrame(this.update);
  }

  onTouchMove (evt) {
    if (!this.touchingSideNav)
      return;

    this.currentX = evt.touches[0].pageX;
    const translateX = Math.min(0, this.currentX - this.startX);

    if (translateX < 0) {
      evt.preventDefault();
    }
  }

  onTouchEnd (evt) {
    if (!this.touchingSideNav)
      return;

    this.touchingSideNav = false;

    const translateX = Math.min(0, this.currentX - this.startX);
    this.sideNavContainerEl.style.transform = '';

    if (translateX < 0) {
      this.hideSideNav();
    }
  }

  update () {
    if (!this.touchingSideNav)
      return;

    requestAnimationFrame(this.update);

    const translateX = Math.min(0, this.currentX - this.startX);
    this.sideNavContainerEl.style.transform = `translateX(${translateX}px)`;
  }

  blockClicks (evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
  }

  onTransitionEnd (evt) {
    this.sideNavEl.classList.remove('side-nav--animatable');
    this.sideNavEl.removeEventListener('transitionend', this.onTransitionEnd);
  }

  showSideNav () {
    console.log('toto');
    this.sideNavEl.classList.add('side-nav--animatable');
    this.sideNavEl.classList.add('side-nav--visible');
    this.detabinator.inert = false;
    this.sideNavEl.addEventListener('transitionend', this.onTransitionEnd);
  }

  hideSideNav () {
    this.sideNavEl.classList.add('side-nav--animatable');
    this.sideNavEl.classList.remove('side-nav--visible');
    this.detabinator.inert = true;
    this.sideNavEl.addEventListener('transitionend', this.onTransitionEnd);
  }

  toggleSideNav () {
    this.showSideNav;
    debugger
  }
}

new SideNav();
```

I also have an `hamburger.js` file to animate my hamburger button but I don't think that cause any trouble.

Thank's for the help.

Comment: do you get any developer tools console errors that may help narrow down the issue?

Comment: this.showSideNav should be invoked as a method in toddleSideNav `this.showSideNav();`

Comment: @JaromandaX No I don't have any issue in the console.

Comment: @DhananjayaKuppu thank's this was the problem but I don't really understand why ? Could you explain it ?

Comment: @Hugo-Contreras Do you not understand how to call a function?

Comment: @Hugo-Contreras addEventListener accepts function as an argument so you need to pass, whenever you need to pass function as an argument to another function parenthesis should not be used. But whenever you need to invoke the function you need to use () then only the statements in that function will be executed.

Comment: Thank's @DhananjayaKuppu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing brackets in the method invocation:

```
toggleSideNav () {
    this.showSideNav;
    debugger // what is that for ?
}
```

Should be:

```
toggleSideNav () {
    this.showSideNav();
    debugger // what is that for ?
}
```

Comment: Thank's for the answer but can you explain why it doesn't work because in my eventListener I did it and it's OK.
`addEventListeners () {
    this.toggleMenuEl.addEventListener('click', this.toggleSideNav);
...`

The `debugger` stop the code and open the dev tools in Chrome. It's a kind of `breakpoint`.

Comment: in the eventListener you are passing to the handler an object that is a function type object. You do not need to invoke the function because the handler will invoke it for you.